# How can update I syntax as a list of one-liners?

Tags: discussion, feature-request, documentation, documentation-editor

> Syntax must be formatted as a list of one-liners

I'm struggling to get over this error while updating a syntax such as this:

```
subscript(index: Int) -> Int {
    get {
        // return an appropriate subscript value here
    }
    set(newValue) {
        // perform a suitable setting action here
    }
}
```

What's the right way to do it? Why syntax editor isn't supporting code formatting similar to other type editors in the site/documention?

Comment: The `syntax` of a function or a class has a very strict interpretation. Try putting that code all on one line and removing the comments, for starters.

Comment: But, @Tyler, that makes the syntax much harder to read, and makes it look like no code anyone would (or *should*, anyway) actually write. The formatting rules of the Syntax section don't currently fit cases where syntax takes multiple lines.

Comment: @RobKennedy That's your opinion that it makes it harder to read. Syntax for a single class or property should fit on a single line. `subscript(index: Int) -> Int { Get {} Set {} }` is not really that hard to read.